# Eclipse GDB in combination with OpenOCD

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, stm32, openocd

I am using `eclipse CDT` to make software for a `stm32f0-discovery` i use `ST-link` to program this controller using usb.

A few days ago i got into debugging my chip using `OpenOCD6.0.1` i followed this tutorial:

[debugger tutorial](http://thehackerworkshop.com/?p=602)

after a few hours i got this working being able to step true my program setting breakpoints and all the other ussual debug stuff. Now, here is were the strange thing happens. I started changing my config from -> Monitor reset halt to -> monitor soft_reset_halt .I did this because i eventually want to develop a board with a stm32f0 series chip wich i can program using only three wires (SWD progrogramming). Because i did not get this to work i restored the setting back to monitor reset halt.

Today i wanted to debug my chip and i ran into the following, when i start to debug eclipse tels me that my device is in its reset handler (this seems correct to me because of the monitor reset halt command) the openocd output at this point is:

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.6.1 (2012-10-07-10:34)
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.sourceforge.net/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
adapter speed: 1000 kHz
srst_only separate srst_nogate srst_open_drain
Info : clock speed 1000 kHz
Info : stm32f0x.cpu: hardware has 4 breakpoints, 2 watchpoints
Info : accepting 'gdb' connection from 3333
Info : device id = 0x20006440
Info : flash size = 64kbytes
Warn : acknowledgment received, but no packet pending
undefined debug reason 6 - target needs reset
target state: halted
target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0xc1000000 pc: 0x0800291c msp: 0x20002000
Info : Padding image section 0 with 4 bytes
target state: halted
target halted due to breakpoint, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x61000000 pc: 0x2000003a msp: 0x20002000
Warn : stepi ignored. GDB will now fetch the register state from the target.
```

Now, i want to step over the reset handler to start my program and then i get this warning:

> Warn : stepi ignored. GDB will now fetch the register state from the
>   target.

after some googling i can' t find any anwser to what is causing this. does anyone have a clue into solving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, i found this one out. Because i use more then one stm32f0discovery board (one on my work, and one for hobby at home). The configuration of the board was different. Thus, i had to update te firmware of the board that wasn' t working. The firmware was 2 versions older then the one i have at home.

Problem solved :)